# Scheduled tasks don't execute when initiated sleep from command line

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, sleep

I have the problem that scheduled tasks will only cause the pc to wake up from sleep, if the PC has been put to sleep with the GUI manually.

However, if I use the command line to suspend the computer the computer will not wake up and the scheduled task will not execute.

I already tried all of the below commands:

1. `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState`
2. `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby`
3. `powercfg -hibernate off` and `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0`

None of those commands works like the GUI does! I also tried forcing S1 instead of S3 sleep in the BIOS. This did not help either. OS is Windows XP. This is perfectly reproducible and very annoying.

How can I suspend the computer from the command line, so it wakes up when a scheduled task is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution: `psshutdown -d -t 0` works!

You can download it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541).

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown /h` has worked for me for years. (C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe)

Comment: Do scheduled tasks wake the computer afterwards?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Yes. Another thing is that in the last few months my Win8 x64 does not execute the task after waking up from hibernation at the prescribed time. I don't know if it's specific to my computer. Maybe I should file it as a separate question? I worked  around it by scheduling twice (7:30 and 7:32) with _Do not start a new instance_ setting.